# Custom hooks with dependency lists and eslint-plugin-react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I have a question regarding eslint-plugin-react-hooks.

I wanted to reduce the boilerplate code of doing a API call and storing the result into state so I created a custom hook:

```
export const loading = Symbol('Api Loading');
export const responseError = Symbol('Api Error');

export function useApi<T>(
    apiCall: () => CancelablePromise<T>,
    deps: DependencyList
): T | (typeof loading) | (typeof responseError) {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState<T | (typeof loading) | (typeof responseError)>(loading);
    useEffect(() => {
        const cancelablePromise = apiCall();
        cancelablePromise.promise
            .then(r => setResponse(r))
            .catch(e => {
                console.error(e);
                setResponse(responseError);
            });
        return () => cancelablePromise.cancel();
    }, deps); // React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'apiCall'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'apiCall' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
    return response;
}
```

Now the custom hook works great but the eslint-plugin-react-hooks not so much.
The warning in my code is not a big problem.
I know i can silence this warning by adding a comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

The problem is that one of the custom hook arguments is a dependency list and eslint-plugin-react-hooks dose not detect missing dependencies on it.
How do I make eslint-plugin-react-hooks correctly detect dependency list problems for my custom hook?
Is it even possible to have such detection for custom hooks?

Comment: Why can you not pass in apiCall as a dependency? (Where is it coming from, anyway?) If that function is changing often (which seems odd), can you memoize it using useCallback as suggested?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule allows you to check your custom hooks. From the [Advanced Configuration](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#advanced-configuration) options:

> exhaustive-deps can be configured to validate dependencies of custom
> Hooks with the additionalHooks option. This option accepts a regex to
> match the names of custom Hooks that have dependencies.
>
> ```json
> {   
>   "rules": {
>     // ...
>     "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": ["warn", {
>       "additionalHooks": "(useMyCustomHook|useMyOtherCustomHook)"
>     }]   
>   }
> }
> ```

In your `.eslintrc` file, add the following entry in the "rules" config:

```json
'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': ['warn', {
      'additionalHooks': '(useApi)'
    }],
```

Then you should be able to call your hook and see the linter warning and use the Quick Fix option.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the dependency lists as arguments in custom hooks are not supported in eslint-plugin-react-hooks (as far as i know).
There is a workaround with useCallback as dangerismycat suggested.

So instead of doing:

```
const apiResult = useApi(() => apiCall(a, b, c), [a, b, c]);
```

The same functionality can be achieved without the custom hook having a dependency list argument:

```
const callback = useCallback(() => apiCall(a, b, c), [a, b, c]);
const apiResult = useApi(callback);
```

While its a shame that it introduces a bit more boilerplate and the code is a bit harder to read, I don't mind it too much.

Comment: Works great with hooks.macro: `const apiResult = useApi(useAutoCallback(() => apiCall(a, b, c))`

Comment: just to clarify, you would then pass `callback` into the deps for `useEffect`:  `const useApi = (cb) => { /* ... */ useEffect(() => { const result = cb(); doSomething(result); }, cb); /* ... */ }`